# pageLoad in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, pageload

In ASP.NET I usually use `pageLoad()` JavaScript function, that gets executed every time the page sends a request even with Ajax (UpdatePanel).

*Is there anything like that in Razor?*

I mean a JavaScript function to get executed for every ajax request without using OnSuccess or something like that in `AjaxOptions`.

Comment: why not use OnSuccess event? i mean you want to do something which is your requirement so you can create a function and call that from your onSuccess event...

Comment: Some actions are common in many `OnSuccess` events. And some of `OnSuccess` event have exactly the same statements.
So I want to have a general function to be executed on every ajax requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a javascript function to run every time your page loads then you need to include the script you want at the <strike>top</strike> bottom of every page you want it to execute on

Then inside of that you'll have the js you want to run.

If you're using jquery then I suggest using $(document).ready()

**Edit**

Alternatively if you want some csharp/vb to run every time your page loads then you need to create a constructor in your controller and place the necessary code in there.

Comment: The jQuery code "$(document).ready()" only get executed on first page load, not on Ajax requests. I want a way for every request in page (Ajax or non-Ajax).

Comment: Then you would need to place some c#/vb in the controller constructor.